# Clean up Docker Compose on exit or crash

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I have some tests in the form of bash scripts that work like this:

1. Start services using `docker-compose`
2. Run test logic
3. Shut down services using `docker-compose`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"

# 1
docker-compose up --detach

# 2
./tests.sh

# 3
docker-compose down --rmi all --remove-orphans
```

The step (2) might fail and crash the script.

How can I ensure that all Docker services from step (1) are shut-down in all cases?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, with a trap:

```
trap_exit() {
   docker-compose down --rmi all --remove-orphans
}
trap trap_exit EXIT

./tests.sh
```